# php mail() to multiple users with composed message and different receivers

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email

I found hardone now (for me).. and I just don't know how to approach that..

So sending mail to one receiver would be easy ..

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

But i want to use difference aproach.. 
i cather some information from users, like e-mail, name etc..
after submiting, that all information goes to db.. afer that will manager add one more field ("racing number") and accepts registration.

When everything is done by manager, i would like to add button what calls php what sends e-mails to all who are in that list (Lets say 100 persons)

Sql would be something like that :

```
SELECT voistlus_nr, voistlus_klass, email, nimi FROM mtma0_mod_romuring_registreerimine
```

now after button press, it should compose for each SQL row different e-mails, and send them to right person..

Reslut example.

SQL result would give :

```
//JOHN
    $racing_number = 1;
    $class = 'Man';
    $email='racer@racing.ee'
    $name='John Smith' 

//Angela    

    $racing_number = 10;
    $class = 'Woman';
    $email='Angela@gmail.something'
    $name='Angela Puu'
```

And recived email to **John** would be then something like that :

**Hello John Smith!
You are registred, your racing number is 1.**

And for **Angela** would it be :

**Hello Angela Puu!
You are registred, your racing number is 10.**

so my logic says that i should add add my SQL result to array and after that loop them all to send all messages 1 by 1?

And the question is.. how to use that Array to send emails.

Answer is below:

```
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $to = $r['email'];
    $name = $r['name'];
    $number = $r['racing_number'];
    $message = "Hello $name! You are registered, your racing number is 
    $number.";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Just use a loop and set the text to the variables

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: Your logic is correct; however you would need to have some flag to mark that email has been sent otherwise in case admin repeats the process with some new records old users would get another email.

Comment: you can use loops to perform this matter.

Comment: @SynapseIndia, good point. i will add something like "mail_status" and collect only thouse who have it "null". Then they dont get the mail.. but then comes question again, how to i set that flag? add all "id-s" to array and after mails are sent i run sql what updates all thouse id-s?

Comment: @Jaanus : " add all "id-s" to array and after mails are sent i run sql what updates all thouse id-s" your logic is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah you are on the right lines, something like the following:

```
$subject = 'the subject';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    $to = $r['email'];
    $name = $r['name'];
    $number = $r['racing_number'];
    $message = "Hello $name! You are registered, your racing number is 
    $number.";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed. 

Only thing what i edited was header : 

'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'. "\r\n" .